# How to send email in background without hard coded credentials?

Tags: android, email, authentication, background, oauth-2.0

I have searched over the site (and the internet), but I haven't found a complete solution yet. Any solutions, examples?

Comment: post to a server (probably a web service) that has the credentials in it.

Answer (score 0):

To send email in background you need to use email client library.

If you don't want to hardcode credentials just make some variables changeable at runtime that you pass to email client.